# Is there a free old version of ExtJS library?

Tags: extjs

Is there a free old version of ExtJS library? Where I can download it? What is the best substitution?

Comment: Everything is better than ExtJS. Belive me, I have to work with an old version on a daily base. *shudder*

Comment: @arkascha brother... 3.3.1 here...

Comment: @CodeWhisperer 3.1 at my job. Can't even find a documentation for it any more...

Comment: @arkascha I have yet to see a grid control as good as ExtJS's. Is there any other I'm not aware of ?

Comment: @arkascha the only thing I go by is API. 3.1 is even worse. Check the questions I asked they cover some issues I encountered might help you out because I know we both need support...

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Never said it does not have strong points. But taking all together I'd say: bad choice.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer LOL, ok, will do so on monday. Weekend already started long ago for me.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme even if you think its good it does not make up for the shortcomings of 3.x.x which are many and serious.

Comment: @arkascha I did not say you said that :) But on the other hand, you can't see it's a bad choice by simply reading a one line question IMO. And by the way, I don't know anything about 3.x. I used 4.2 and it was a breeze...with a steep learning curve.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme yes if you have to deal with ExtJS use 4.0 and up. Any older versions is hell. Same learning curve with the added benefit of minor to serious bugs with no support. If you go on their forums trying to find a fix for a bug in 3.x.x the answer usually is "we fixed it in 4.x". Well gee thanks all I gotta do now is migrate the whole thing to 4.x which is borderline impossible if you have a lot of code in 3.x

Comment: I hate ExtJS 3.3.1. It's 2019 and we are adding enhancements to an app written in this version.  It's a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

I work a lot with ExtJS 3.3.1 and I would highly recommend not to go lower then 4.0.

They made a very large update at 4.0 which requires a lot of migration effort from 3.3.1.

If you are starting a new program start with 4.0 at least. Don't set up yourself for the pain of 3.3.1. It has many bugs, no support, and you can barely find answers for it online because it is so old and unused.

4.0 and up has much more support and content.

If you have a choice I would recommend not to use ExtJS at all and go for AngularJS or something else.

Comment: AFAIK, AngularJS doesn't seem to have UI widgets, while ExtJS (4.x+) has loads of them. If I'm right about this, both can't really be compared then.

Comment: Usually you use Angular + bootstrap from what I know. Bootstrap gives you the UI. But yes ExtJS has everything in one package and steep learning curve.

Comment: Yep check it out its pretty neat from the little amount I spent with it. The UI looks very nice (in my opinion) and it requires little coding to create the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik recently made part of the Kendo UI free.  Might give it a look.  It's called Kendo UI Core.

Comment: Thanks, but where I can get a free ExtJS any version and?

Comment: My potential subcontract employer insists on using ExtJS. Are AngularJS Kendo UI and JQuery better?